# How worthy is Captain America?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, captain-america

In the movie, Thor allowed the rest of the Avengers to try and lift Mjolnir, confident that they aren't worthy. Most of them failed, ofc. The Cap, however, managed to budge the hammer ever so slightly, and was the only time Thor's confidence faltered for an instant, showing on his face. Thor obviously noticed what escaped everyone else, even the Captain himself.

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.

With that in mind, how worthy is Captain America? How/why is he more worthy than the rest but still less than Thor himself?

Comment: Is there something [in this question] that doesn't address yours? What would you like to know that's different?

Comment: When they define "worthy" in concrete numbers, we can better assess this.

Answer (score 2):

**How worthy is Captain America?**

As per the comic counterpart, he is worthy enough to hold the hammer, but in the MCU, he is not worthy <strike>yet</strike>.

There are a few internet speculations that he didn't lift the hammer intentionally in the film after seeing Thor's face but there is no proof of it.

**How/why is he more worthy than the rest but still less than Thor himself?**

We don't know. There is no worthy percentage as per the comics-verse and this scene was just a joke/fun moment and a partial nod to Captain America being worthy. There is no in-depth motive for it and it was never established like that.

Comment: Don't forget this scene also set the stage later for another character who proved their worthiness by lifting the hammer